Expose api-docs based on Accept header with Springdoc
I have used Springdoc to autogenerate the api documentation and it works like a charm but, I am suffering some issues integrating the documentation of the API on the company documentation system.
My configuration of Springdoc
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
     <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api</artifactId>
     <version>${openapi-spring.version}</version>
 </dependency>
...

 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
     <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>${openapi.version}</version>
     <executions>
        <execution>
           <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
             <verbose>false</verbose>
             <inputSpecRootDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/static</inputSpecRootDirectory>
              <generatorName>kotlin-spring</generatorName>
              <library>spring-boot</library>
              <configOptions>
                 <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                 <basePackage>com.kk.jobinstantapply</basePackage>
                 <apiPackage>com.kk.jobinstantapply.api</apiPackage>
                 <modelPackage>com.kk.jobinstantapply.api.model</modelPackage>
                 <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                 <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
               </configOptions>
           </configuration>
         </execution>
       </executions>
 </plugin>


When I execute this:
curl --location '127.0.0.1:8080/rest/job-instant-apply/vendor

It returns in json format, as expected.
The problem appears when the system that shows API documentation is doing a GET call to the api doc of my project. They include the header Accept=application/vnd.kk.vendor-documentation+json and my documentation endpoint fails.
curl --location '127.0.0.1:8080/rest/job-instant-apply/vendor' --header 'Accept: application/vnd.kk.vendor-documentation+json'

returns a 500 and this response:
{
    "error": "No acceptable representation"
}

These are the logs I see:
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: No acceptable representation
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:285)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:441)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:382)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:126)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:68)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:505)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1275)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at com.kk.jobinstantapply.api.TransactionFilter.doFilter(RoutingController.kt:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at com.kk.logjam.web.LogjamWebFilter.doFilter(LogjamWebFilter.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

I understand that Springdoc is expecting a component that produces this special media type and since it is not there, application fails.
I could easily fix this adding the annotationproduces = ["application/vnd.kk.vendor-documentation+json"] but, the documentation is autogenerated. I do not know how to properly fix this.
I have tried different approaches:

Configuring springdoc. Documentation is not really clear but I tried to set to application/vnd.kk.vendor-documentation+json the following properties: springdoc.produces-to-match, springdoc.headers-to-match, springdoc.default-produces-media-type but none of them seems to do the magic I need, eg:

springdoc:
  pathsToMatch: /rest/job-instant-apply/vendor/**
  produces-to-match: application/vnd.kk.vendor-documentation+json
  api-docs:
    path: /rest/job-instant-apply/vendor
    version: OPENAPI_3_1
  ui:
    url: ./api.yml


I tried to define a @GetMapping component to capture the Accept header and redirect to the api endpoint but it fails because original headers are also being sent, and my api doc endpoint fails again. I tried several redirect methods with the same unexpected results:

@GetMapping(value = ["/rest/job-instant-apply/kk"],
        produces = ["application/vnd.kk.vendor-documentation+json"])
    fun method(httpServletResponse: HttpServletResponse) {
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", "/rest/job-instant-apply/kk2")
        println(httpServletResponse.headerNames.toString())
        httpServletResponse.status = 302
    }

and
    @RequestMapping(
        value = ["/rest/job-instant-apply/kk"],
        produces = ["application/vnd.kk.vendor-documentation+json"]
    )
    fun localRedirect(): RedirectView? {
        val redirectView = RedirectView()
        redirectView.url = "/rest/job-instant-apply/kk2"
        return redirectView
    }


I tried to redirect and overwrite the headers, but apparently is not possible. I tried implementing a doFilter

@Component
@Order(1)
class TransactionFilter : Filter {
    @Throws(ServletException::class)
    override fun doFilter(
        request: ServletRequest,
        response: ServletResponse,
        chain: FilterChain
    ) {
        chain.doFilter(request, object : HttpServletResponseWrapper(response as HttpServletResponse) {
            override fun addHeader(name: String, value: String) {
                if (!name.equals("Accept", ignoreCase = true) || !name.equals("Content-Type", ignoreCase = true)) {
                    super.addHeader(name, value)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}


Instead of performing a redirect, reading the open-api documentation I see that we can customize the documentation. I just returned the OpenApi bean, but it returned an empty report.

    @GetMapping(value = ["/rest/job-instant-apply/kk"],
        produces = ["application/vnd.kk.vendor-documentation+json"])
    fun localRedirect(openAPI: OpenAPI): OpenAPI {
        return openAPI
    }

I have the impression I should move in 4 direction but I am blocked. Do you have any idea about how to proceed?

Can you clarify which system is making the get call?  The problem appears when the system that shows API documentation is doing a GET call to the api doc of my project.
